# How to write a url request along with parameters so it returns string?

Tags: ios, url

I have a url , and two parameters to pass before making request. What I am doing is appending values of all the url, parameterA, and parameterB.

```
NSString*urlString=@"www.example.com";
NSString*paramA=@"day=20140715";
NSString*paramA=@"mode=2ndMode";
   NSArray *URLArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:urlString,paramA,paramB, nil];
        NSString *helloString = [URLArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
 NSData *dataA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:helloString];
 NSString *responseSt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataA encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

NOW THIS IS EASY WAY DOING A CONNECTION, BUT HOW DO WE WRITE A METHOD FOR URL REQUEST IN A PROPER WAY?
Something that returns string after the request is complete.

```
-(void)url(NSString*)helloString ParameterA(NSString*)paramA ParameterB(NSString*)paramB ??
```

Comment: You will get response object from your server, if you want to return a string then return a string from server, it totally depends on you what you want to return after calling a request to server.

Comment: I want to write a request for example 
-(void)url(NSString*)helloString ParameterA(NSString*)paramA ParameterB(NSString*)paramB

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> NSString*url = @"www.example.com";
> NSString*paramA = @"day=20140715";
> NSString*paramB = @"mode=2ndMode";
> NSArray *params = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:paramA,paramB, nil];
> NSString *URLStr = [params componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
> URLStr = [url stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@",URLStr];
> NSData *dataA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLStr]];
> NSString *responseSt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataA encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
> ```

Try this code.